# Node.js: Juggling Async (learnyounode). Recursion in callback functions not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

So I was solving this `learnyounode` exercise called *Juggling Async*, which basically gives me 3 URLs and asks me to output the URL content, in the order of the URLs input.

I came up with a recursive solution, in which a callback calls another callback while maintaining an exit counter `num`. However, when I run this, I keep getting blank lines on the console, no matter what the input.

This is the short code:

```
var url = ["", process.argv[2], process.argv[3], process.argv[4]];
var http = require('http');
var str = ["", "", "", ""];

var cnt = 1;

function dos(num, callback)
{
    if(num == 4)
        return;
    http.get(url[num], function (response1){
    //  console.log(num);
        response1.setEncoding('utf8');
        response1.on('data', function(data1) {
            str[num] = data1;
            callback(num + 1, dos);

        })
    });
}

dos(1, dos);
console.log(str[1]);
console.log(str[2]);
console.log(str[3]);
```

Now, this is my first time pulling off recursion with callback functions. I learned callback functions just two days ago, which might mean that there is something glaringly wrong here which I cannot see. Please help me see. Thank you.

Comment: Have you even tried logging `data1` to see what is the returned content in first place?

Comment: I had not. I tried logging data1 inside the `response1.on('data'` block now. There is content, but it gets logged multiple times. This might mean something is wrong with the recursion, or the event is being emitted multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the execution order.

1. You define the `dos` function
2. You invoke the `dos` function
3. You invoke the `console.log`

The problem with your code is asynchronous nature of the `http.get` method.

In the definition of `dos` whenever `http.get` is invoked, a callback is attached and after that control flow exists the function scope. Control flow is not stopping and waiting for the `get` call to complete.

It exits the function scope and moves onto invoking `console.log` so you get blank strings because that's what your array contains at that moment.

For you to achieve your expected result.

In the function call instead of assigning the value of `data1` to `str[num]`. Do a simple `console.log(data1)` in place.

If you still prefer the outside `console.log` placement in your code. You read about `async\await`.

`dos` invokation must return a `Promise`.

Comment: _It exits the function scope and moves onto invoking console.log so you get blank strings because that's what your array contains at that moment._
























I am probably wrong, but shouldn't control flow exit function scope after all the recursive callbacks have returned?

Comment: No, think about the difference between asynchronous and synchronous execution. You expect the behavior to be synchronous, but name callback is self-explanatory. It registers an action to be taken when a certain event occurs. in your case `http.get` doesn't returns anything. Neither do the values returned from the callbacks are accessible anywhere.